# Glide not loading image if its same url

Tags: android, android-glide

I need to load image using Glide. The url won't be changing, its only the image that gets changed. So the new image is not getting loaded. If I give skipMemoryCache true and DiskCacheStrategy NONE, it will load always. I want only the image to get updated when the content has changed.

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(url)
     .asBitmap()
     .centerCrop()
     .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
     .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
     .error(R.drawable.error)
     .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(imageview) {
          @override
          protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
               RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                                     RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory
                                     .create(context.getResources(),
                                             resource);
               circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
               imageview.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
      }
});
```

Comment: Glide use url as picture key in device cache, so when you change your picture you have to change url also.